# Having trouble with new field in entity (unrecognized selector error)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, unrecognized-selector

I'm trying to add a field to an entity and whenever I try to access the new field I get

> unrecognized selector sent to instance...

Everything else about the entity works.  I'm able to add objects and I'm able to assign values to other fields in the object, but not to the new objects.

Of note, I also deleted the `DerivedData` directory and I deleted the `.mom/.momd` files to make sure the tables are being built correctly.

Any thoughts?

Locations.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Games, Players;

@interface Locations : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * defaultLoc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * locationAddr1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * locationAddr2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * locationCity;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * locationID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * locationName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * locationState;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * locationZip;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * numberOfCourts;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * defLoc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *haveGames;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *havePlayers;
@end

@interface Locations (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addHaveGamesObject:(Games *)value;
- (void)removeHaveGamesObject:(Games *)value;
- (void)addHaveGames:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeHaveGames:(NSSet *)values;

- (void)addHavePlayersObject:(Players *)value;
- (void)removeHavePlayersObject:(Players *)value;
- (void)addHavePlayers:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeHavePlayers:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

Locations.m

```
#import "Locations.h"
#import "Games.h"
#import "Players.h"


@implementation Locations

@dynamic defaultLoc;
@dynamic locationAddr1;
@dynamic locationAddr2;
@dynamic locationCity;
@dynamic locationID;
@dynamic locationName;
@dynamic locationState;
@dynamic locationZip;
@dynamic numberOfCourts;
@dynamic defLoc;
@dynamic haveGames;
@dynamic havePlayers;

@end
```

Note:  defLoc and defaultLoc are two fields that I added.  These are the ones giving me problems.

Executing code:

```
- (IBAction)updateLocation:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    // If it is not "Edit" it is an "Add" and we need to insert a newobject.
    if ([segueType1 isEqualToString:@"Add"])
    {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[self fetchedResultsController] managedObjectContext];
        location = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Locations" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    }
    location.locationName   = lName;
    location.locationAddr1  = lAddr1;
    location.locationAddr2  = lAddr2;
    location.locationCity   = lCity;
    location.locationState  = lState;
    location.locationZip    = lZip;
    location.numberOfCourts = lNumCourts;
    location.defLoc = lNumCourts;
//    location.defaultLoc = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
//    DLog(@"ldefaultLocation = %@",ldefaultLocation);
    location.defaultLoc = ldefaultLocation;
    segueType1 = @"Add";  //  Always reset back to Add so that segues work right
}
```

location.defLoc above is the command that gives the error...All other location statements work fine.

Comment: Did you create a new Core Data model version? If yes, did you set the "current version" to the new version?

Comment: This seemed to be the right answer as I hadn't done this before.  I did the research on how to implement, did the process, tried deleting things as some advised...Still no luck :-(  Same message

Answer (score 0):

That can happen when you don't declare the new attribute in your NSManagedObject child. As soon as you add a new field in the core data model, remember to add the right property to the NSManagedObject class and declare it @dynamic in the implementation.

Comment: I ran the "Create NSManagedOBject..." from the menu and double checked to make sure it created the property in the .h for the entity.  I even ran twice to make sure everything built correctly...all seems normal (except for this error message)....Also checked the .m.  It does have @dynamic.

Comment: Ok, could you then post some more code? Like: the set of properties in the NSManagedObject child and the statement you use to instantiate a new entity